# I can only get error NSScanner: nil string argument,why

Tags: objective-c

When my program crash, I'm only getting this warning NSScanner: nil string argument in the debug window.

And I did not use the class NSScaner

How do I resolve this problem ?

Comment: Show the whole error message, show the line where is crash. An use of `NSScanner` may be done in the code of a method that "you don't see".

Comment: whenever crashed,I can only get debug message as  2015-03-04 18:19:47.605 Ymatou[4234:1894498] NSScanner: nil string argument
2015-03-04 18:19:47.605 Ymatou[4234:1894498] NSScanner: nil string argument
libc++abi.dylib: terminate_handler unexpectedly threw an exception

Comment: Try to find out which line causes the crash.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Obj-C, NSScanner: nil string argument, suddenly getting this warning, how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8113139/obj-c-nsscanner-nil-string-argument-suddenly-getting-this-warning-how-do-i-f)

Comment: Or check @Jeremy W. Sherman's answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7095174/what-causes-nsscanner-nil-string-argument. NSDecimal initwithString: produces this error as well.

Answer (score 0):

You may get this warning if you take a nil object as the argument of some method. So, find out the scope where this error could take place and check all methods carefully, especially those who takes string as the argument